# Scrape multiple URLs with rvest

Tags: html, r, screen-scraping, rvest

How can I scrape multiple urls when using the `read_html` in `rvest`? The goal is to obtain a single document consisting of the text bodies from the respective urls on which to run various analyses.

I tried to concatenate the urls:

```
 url <- c("https://www.vox.com/","https://www.cnn.com/")
   page <-read_html(url)
   page
   story <- page %>%
        html_nodes("p") %>%  
        html_text
```

After `read_html` get an error:

```
 Error in doc_parse_file(con, encoding = encoding, as_html = as_html, options = options) : 
 Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=3].
```

Not surprised since the `read_html` probably only handles one path at a time. However, can I use a different function or transformation so several pages can be scraped simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` (or in base R: `lapply`) to loop through every `url` element; here is an example

```r
url <- c("https://www.vox.com/", "https://www.bbc.com/")
page <-map(url, ~read_html(.x) %>% html_nodes("p") %>% html_text())
str(page)
#List of 2
# $ : chr [1:22] "But he was acquitted on the two most serious charges he faced." "Health experts say it’s time to prepare for worldwide spread on all continents." "Wall Street is waking up to the threat of coronavirus as fears about the disease and its potential global econo"| __truncated__ "Johnson, who died Monday at age 101, did groundbreaking work in helping return astronauts safely to Earth." ...
# $ : chr [1:19] "" "\n                                                            The ex-movie mogul is handcuffed and led from cou"| __truncated__ "" "27°C" ...
```

The return object is a `list`.

PS. I've changed the second `url` element because `"https://www.cnn.com/"` returned `NULL` for `html_nodes("p") %>% html_text()`.

Comment: Thanks @Maurits Evers - this is very helpful! The map-function worked after running 'Purrr'. But I too have problems running certain URLs. I get: character (0) when running 'html_nodes' on various URLs. I wonder if I have a selector problem.  I wonder how I can I set the html_nodes to catch all selector classes and return text?

Comment: @AnneBoysen That seems to be a different question that you'd probably want to ask in a new post. I suggest closing this question by setting the green check mark next to the answer; then open a new question with a clear problem statement. Happy to take a look.